# Create a sequence of numbers from a repeating set (e.g. months)

Tags: r

Is there a simple, base r approach to create a sequence of numbers from a broader REPEATING set?
For instance, thinking of months of the year, how can I create a sequence based on start /end months such that:

```
>fx(5:10)
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

but also that

```
>fx(10:3)
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3
```

I know this is possible based on a few lines of inelegant code, but I am sure there is something simple and concise out there.

Comment: Check out `length.out=` in `rep()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very elegant, but it is a single line that does the trick, as long as the sequence is a set of integers from `1:m`.

```
fx <- function(f, l, m) (y <- (1:m)[c(f:m, 2:f - 1)])[1:which(y == l)]
```

```
> fx(5, 10, m = 12)                                                                                                   
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10                                                                                                 
> fx(10, 3, m = 12)                                                                                                   
[1] 10 11 12  1  2  3
```

Comment: Both answers provided are quite simple/elegant! Sasha was first in providing a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

One option using the modulo:

```
f <- function(start, end, max) (seq(start, end + (end < start) * max) - 1) %% max + 1

f(5, 10, 12)
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10

f(10, 3, 12)
[1] 10 11 12  1  2  3
```